# Size command is not recognized, thought installed correctly

Tags: command-line, osx

I am working on macOs and tried size command on cc

```
$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc
```

it does not work correctly

```
$ size /usr/bin/cc
size: /usr/bin/cc: unknown load command 0x32
size: /usr/bin/cc: unknown load command 0x32
size: /usr/bin/cc: unknown load command 0x32
size: /usr/bin/cc: file format not recognized

$ size /bin/ls
size: /bin/ls: unknown load command 0x32
size: /bin/ls: unknown load command 0x32
size: /bin/ls: unknown load command 0x32
size: /bin/ls: file format not recognized
```

and the size is latest version

```
$ size --version
GNU size (GNU Binutils) 2.31.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

but on Centos

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# size /usr/bin/cc
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 754853    8488   81856  845197   ce58d /usr/bin/cc
```

What's the problem with command size?

```
$ file /usr/bin/cc
/usr/bin/cc: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64


$ size --help
Usage: size [option(s)] [file(s)]
 Displays the sizes of sections inside binary files
 If no input file(s) are specified, a.out is assumed
 The options are:
  -A|-B     --format={sysv|berkeley}  Select output style (default is berkeley)
  -o|-d|-x  --radix={8|10|16}         Display numbers in octal, decimal or hex
  -t        --totals                  Display the total sizes (Berkeley only)
            --common                  Display total size for *COM* syms
            --target=<bfdname>        Set the binary file format
            @<file>                   Read options from <file>
  -h        --help                    Display this information
  -v        --version                 Display the program's version
```

this works

```
me at Max-2018 in ~/desktop
$ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/size /usr/bin/cc
__TEXT  __DATA  __OBJC  others  dec hex
4096    4096    0   4294979584  4294987776  100005000   


$ ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin | grep size
llvm-size
size
size-classic
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? cc is not an object file.

Comment: it does not work on any command. @jordanm

Comment: Do you have the macos Command Line Tool package installed?  `size` is one of the binaries from this and it works just fine for me on High Sierra.

Comment: What is the output of `file /usr/bin/cc` and of `size --help`

Comment: @Jordanm `size` can work on executable.

Comment: How did you install `size`?  Is it possible you've updated OS X, but not the xcode command line tools?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it. `$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
` @JRFerguson

Comment: I updated my question. @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: Did you chop the bottom off of the output of `size --help`?

Comment: It appears that you have installed GNU `size` despite having the Command Line Tools package installed. Does `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/size` work?

Comment: yes, it works, how could it be? could you please transmit the comment to answer. @JRFerguson

Comment: Please provide your Mac OS version and the output of `which size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have installed GNU's `size` despite having the Command Line Tools package installed as you noted. Try: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/size`.

If your OS is El Capitan (10.11) or later, you have to disable [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) (at least temporarily) in order to install into directories like /bin, /sbin and /usr (but not /usr/local).

Comment: ty, `$ which size
/usr/local/bin/size` and the version is mojove